# How to sort a List of objects by their date (java collections, List<Object>)

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
private List<Movie> movieItems = null;
public List<Movie> getMovieItems() {
    final int first = 0;
    if (movieItems == null) {
        getPagingInfo();
        movieItems = jpaController.findRange(new int[]{pagingInfo.getFirstItem(), pagingInfo.getFirstItem() + pagingInfo.getBatchSize()});
        Collections.sort(movieItems, new Comparator(){
           public int compare (Object o1, Object o2){
               Date d1 = movieItems.get(((Movie)o1).getMovieId()).getDate();
               Date d2 = movieItems.get(((Movie)o2).getMovieId()).getDate();
               if(d1.before(d2)){
                   movieItems.set(1, (Movie)o1);
                   movieItems.set(2, (Movie)o2);
               }
               return first;
           }
       });
    }
    return movieItems;
}
```

jpaController is bringing back 4 movies and is giving me the following

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 4
>     at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:694)    at
>   entitybeans.jsf.PeliculaController$1.compare(PeliculaController.java:260)
>     at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)     at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)   at
>   java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)  at
>   entitybeans.jsf.PeliculaController.getPeliculaItems(PeliculaController.java:257)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)     at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)....

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In your `compare` method, `o1` and `o2` are already elements in the `movieItems` list. So, you should do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(movieItems, new Comparator<Movie>() {
    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
        return m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());
    }
});
```

Comment: it's `m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());` me think

Comment: @AdrienBe, i think you are correct. pwc, please include adrien's suggestion in your answer.

Comment: am using this code working fine. i need get data between two dates(start,end) from arraylist..how can i change that code?

Answer (score 22):

Do not access or modify the collection in the `Comparator`. The comparator should be used only to determine which object is comes before another. The two objects that are to be compared are supplied as arguments.

`Date` itself is comparable, so, using generics:

```
class MovieComparator implements Comparator<Movie> {
    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
       //possibly check for nulls to avoid NullPointerException
       return m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());
    }
}
```

And do not instantiate the comparator on each sort. Use:

```
private static final MovieComparator comparator = new MovieComparator();
```

Answer (score 21):

In Java 8+, it's now as simple as:

```
movieItems.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getDate));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks java8 and @bphilipnyc!

Answer (score 16):

You're using `Comparators` incorrectly.

```
 Collections.sort(movieItems, new Comparator<Movie>(){
           public int compare (Movie m1, Movie m2){
               return m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());
           }
       });
```

Comment: But, `movieItems` is a list of `Movie` objects, not `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add Commons NullComparator instead to avoid some problems...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Collections.sort(list, org.joda.time.DateTimeComparator.getInstance());
```

Comment: Joda is a large framework to import so unless you're using more functions from the framework, I would not recommend this method.