# Sort List by dates when the first date is today

Tags: java

Currently I am trying to sort my list by dates:

```
Collections.sort(unsortedDates, new Comparator<Item>() {
    public int compare(Item m1, Item m2) {
        return m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());
    }
});
```

But I want the list to be sorted so the anchor date will be today, the first item should be the closest date for the current date.

The date format is `MM/dd`.

`getDate()` returns a `Date` object.

Comment: What is the type of date? A String? A Date object?

Comment: what is the expected behaviour for past dates?

Comment: the past dates should come last

Answer (score 5):

Create today's date outside the comparator, and change your comparator to compare absolute differences for the dates it compares, like this:

```
final long todayTime = new Date().getTime();
Collections.sort(unsortedDates, new Comparator<Item>() {
    public int compare(Item m1, Item m2) {
        long dist1 = Math.abs(todayTime-m1.getDate().getTime());
        long dist2 = Math.abs(todayTime-m2.getDate().getTime());
        return Long.compare(dist1, dist2);
    }
});
```

Comment: It sorts the dates so the first date is 12/12 and the last date is 1/1.

Comment: @user1940676 Swap `dist1` and `dist2` in the call of `Long.compare` to reverse the order.

Comment: It still does not start from 8/18 , but from 1/1.

Comment: @user1940676 Then it must be the `1/1` of a different year. Do you want the year portion ignored?

Answer (score 3):

Code for Java 1.5+ (autoboxing).

```
final long current = (new Date()).getTime();
Collections.sort(unsortedDates, new Comparator<Item>() {
    public int compare(Item m1, Item m2) {
        Long m1diff = Math.abs(m1.getDate().getTime() - current);
        Long m2diff = Math.abs(m2.getDate().getTime() - current);
        return m1diff.compareTo(m2diff);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This guy has pretty much the same code as you in his answer. Maybe worth checking out.

[Sort a List of Objects by Their Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207029/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-their-date-java-collections-listobject)

Or you have this, but it uses an ArrayList so it may not be what you're looking for, but somewhat similar.

[Sort Objects in ArrayList by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date)